# Running @MainActor in non isolated context with Thread.isMainThread check

Tags: ios, swift, swift-concurrency

I have a non-isolated property. Inside this I need to check whether it's being called from the main thread. If it is, then I want to immediately call a main actor isolated function. I have tried the following:

```
var myProperty: Bool {
  if Thread.isMainThread {
    performMainActorIsolatedFunction()
  }
  ...
  return true
}
```

However, it gives me the error:

```
Call to main actor-isolated instance method 'performMainActorIsolatedFunction()' in a synchronous nonisolated context.
```

How can I get this to work without marking `myProperty` with `@MainActor`?

Comment: The correct solution is, as you’ve noted, to mark this property as being isolated to the main actor and retire this main thread test. So, we should ask the question as to why you are reticent to do that.

Comment: @Rob I'm reluctant to because a load of code is non-async and relies on accessing that property in multiple places and requires a lot of work to update, which is why I'm trying to keep it as non isolated for now.